# Perl: Providing Individual Array references from AoA to a function

Tags: perl

Without going into all the details since they're irrelevant assume you have a variable number of arrays within another array in Perl:

```
@Models = ( [@m1], [@m2] .... [@m_x]);
```

Later, I have a function that requires passing individual arrays as such:

```
somefunc(\@m1, \@m2, ... \@m_x);
```

Since the number of arrays is variable (`x`) is there an easy way to generate the parameter list for `somefunc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `somefunc` has no prototype, then

```
somefunc(\@m1, \@m2, ... \@m_x);
```

and

```
my @Models = (\@m1, \@m2, .... \@m_x);
somefunc(@Models);
```

are the same thing. If `somefunc` does have a prototype, just bypass it.

```
my @Models = (\@m1, \@m2, .... \@m_x);
&somefunc(@Models);
```